# Camera ip streaming in webview android

Tags: android, video, webview, streaming, ip-camera

I have made car with camera device which provide ip address by calling this http request is being hit, camera video is showing in deskstop browser but not working in mobile browser i want to show camera's video in android webview is there any possibility to do this in webview.

Comment: Some user downvote my answers, and moderator delete it, I don't care, just want to help. You can use this awesome https://github.com/niqdev/ipcam-view library It also handle to input credential

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to use your mobile browser in this case. I recommend you using third party apps like [IP Cam Viewer][1] https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rcreations.ipcamviewerBasic  to view your ip cam.